# Updating forms with NGRX returns ViewDestroyedError

Tags: angular, ngrx

So I load my form from an API into the store. I render the form from the store. But when I update my store fields it does not update the fields in the view.

I call this on my `ngOnInit()`

```
this.store.select((state) => state.forms).subscribe((forms) => {
  const form = forms.sliderForms[FormNames.AddEmployeeForm];
  if (form) {
    this.initializeFormControls(form.slides);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
});
```

And initialize the form controls this way:

```
  initializeFormControls(slides: Slide[]) {
    this.data = slides;
    this.data.forEach((slide: Slide) => {
      const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
      slide.fields.forEach((field: Field) => {
        if (field) {
          // Set form control and its' validators
          formGroup.addControl(field.id, this.fb.control(field.value));
        }
      });
      this.mainGroup.addControl(slide.formName, formGroup);
    });
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

I send the controls to the child components in the view:

```
<form *ngIf="data; else loading" [formGroup]="mainGroup">
  <app-slides (slider)="getSlider($event)">
    <app-slide *ngFor="let slide of data; let i = index" [title]="slide.title" [formGroupName]="slide.formName">
      <app-field *ngFor="let field of slide.fields" [field]="field" [group]="mainGroup.controls[slide.formName]"></app-field>
    </app-slide>
  </app-slides>
</form>
```

So these are called everytime there is a change in the store. Why does my view not change the value when I update them?

If I remove the whole field from the store it does change.

If I leave the page and return, the value is updated.

EDIT:

This is the Field component

```
export class FieldComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() field: Field = new Field();
  @Input() group: FormGroup;
  @Input() formName: string;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<IAppState>,
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select((state) => state.forms).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.field) {
        console.log(this.group.controls[this.formName]); // Gives old value every time
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Running detectChanges on a parent component is not going to force a child to run a change detection cycle. Try binding the slide to your child component and not the field forcing the child to refresh since slide should have a new reference after each update.

Comment: It is binded to my child component. I editted my question to contain the child view.

Comment: The Input that is changing when you add information to any of your fields should be the [field] = "field" in your app-field component. And for me the problem is that you are binding to field and not to slide directly which has a new reference every time your subscription triggers. And I assume also that you use OnPush change detection and this is why you are calling it manually on a few occasions.

Comment: I only send the `field` to get the name of the field. I also send a reference of the form group. But what you said made me think it is because I send a reference of the FormGroup within the main FormGroup instead of the main FormGroup. Could it be that that is the actual problem or am I wrong here? (field is not a FormControl)

Comment: My assumption was wrong..

Comment: Well the main idea is that the inputs to your child element are not changing their reference when your subscription is triggered. If you want to hack it just bind a dummy input that gets a new reference every time your subscription is fired.

Comment: I managed to do it in a somewhat better way thanks to your inspiration :) The `field` input also contains the value of the field. So instead of only passing the name of the field I pass the whole field. And in the last child I subscribe to the store and set the value of the FormControl. If you want you can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Great. I am happy to have helped. I am not here for the points. Take care.